# How do I create an app on QlikSense using QRS API?

Tags: qliksense

We just installed and configured Qlik Sense of a machine with all the necessary steps and everything is correct, because we tested using the QRS API about endpoint ( /about ). We are using Java so the QRS API it's the desired option

My question is the following : when a user makes an account into our application we want to create for him an app in Qlik Sense with his username using QRS API but the documentation isn't very clear about the endpoints and data we need to provide.

https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/April2020/Subsystems/RepositoryServiceAPI/Content/Sense_RepositoryServiceAPI/RepositoryServiceAPI-App-Upload-App.htm 
Here it says that we need to provide a QVF file but we don't know where we should get that file

Can you please provide us with a step by step guide on how to achieve this as we are new to this platform ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Engine` is responsible for the app creation. The `Repository` can only import already existing apps (qvf files)

Most of the `Engine API` is [websocket JSON API](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/April2020/Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/Sense_EngineAPI/introducing-engine-API.htm) but Qlik is exposing small subset of the `Engine API` as [REST as well](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/April2020/APIs/QIXAPI/index.html)

In your case I think you can use [POST /v1/apps](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/April2020/APIs/QIXAPI/index.html?page=25) method to create an app

If you do prefer to use the websocket API you can have a look at [Create an app](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/April2020/Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/Sense_EngineAPI/CreatingAppLoadingData/CreateApps/create-app.htm) example

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Unfortunately we have to use the newest version of Qlik. I found this : https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/April2020/APIs/RepositoryServiceAPI/index.html?page=318  but I don't know what the "path (required)binary" means as Request Body. Can you please help out ?

Comment: The `path` (not sure why its named like this) is the actual `qvf` file. You have to have the file generated already in order to import it. For this method the file is passed to the repository api in the body of the request

Comment: How we can generate the qvf file ? I don't see an endpoint to do so

Comment: The Repository itself can't create files. Create files is handled by the Engine. Engine and Repository are two different components. The main way to communicate with the Engine is via websocket API but it expose some REST endpoints as well. Have a look at https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/April2020/APIs/QIXAPI/index.html?page=25 

Once the Engine creates the app then there is no need to use the Repository to upload the app. Use the Repository to only upload apps which are created outside the current QS instance